# Create a time series chart showing the winter, spring, summer, and fall mean land surface temperatures (LST) on the same graph

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I know how to create a time series for each season, but I how can I plot them on the same chart?

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.08412, 37.42189]);
Map.centerObject(roi, 6); 
print('Coordinates for ROI', roi.coordinates());

// Load MODIS Image Collection
var mod11a2 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A2')
  .filterDate('2001-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  
//convert K to Celsius. 
    .map(function(img) {
    return img.clip(roi)
      .multiply(0.02)
      .subtract(273.15)
      .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
  });

// 2001-2022 LST.
var YR = mod11a2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 12, 'month'));
var winterR = mod11a2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12, 2, 'month'));
var springR = mod11a2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3, 5, 'month'));
var summerR = mod11a2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'));
var fallR = mod11a2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(9, 11, 'month'));

//print('Filtered Year Round (2001-2022)', YR);
//print('Filtered Winter (2001-2022)', winterR);
//print('Filtered Spring (2001-2022)', springR);
//print('Filtered Summer (2001-2022)', summerR);
//print('Filtered Fall (2001-2022)', fallR);

//Calculate the 2001-2022 mean and add layer to map.
var YRm = YR.mean();
Map.addLayer(YRm, {  
  min: -25, max: 45,
  palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']},
  '2001-2022 Mean');
  
//Create time series charts for mean LST in each season and YR.
var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: YR,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: '2001-2022 Year Round LST Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST ( °C)'}});
print(ts1);

var ts2 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: winterR,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: '2001-2022 Winter LST Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST ( °C)'}});
print(ts2);

var ts3 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: springR,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: '2001-2022 Spring LST Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST ( °C)'}});
print(ts3);

var ts4 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: summerR,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: '2001-2022 Summer LST Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST ( °C)'}});
print(ts4);

var ts5 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: fallR,
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: '2001-2022 Autumn LST Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST ( °C)'}});
print(ts5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance turn your image collections into a feature collection, turn each image into a feature with the mean calculated using `reduceRegion()` and a property specifying which season the feature comes from. Then you can chart your feature collection using `ui.Chart.feature.groups()`.

```
var filterBySeason = ee.Dictionary({
  'Year Round': ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 12, 'month'),
  'Winter': ee.Filter.calendarRange(12, 2, 'month'),
  'Spring': ee.Filter.calendarRange(3, 5, 'month'),
  'Summer': ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'),
  'Winter': ee.Filter.calendarRange(9, 11, 'month')
})

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(filterBySeason.keys()
  .map(
    function(season) {
      return ee.FeatureCollection(mod11a2
        .filter(ee.Filter(filterBySeason.get(ee.String(season))))
        .map(function(image) {
          var properties = image
            .reduceRegion({
              reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
              geometry: roi,
              scale: 1000,
              maxPixels: 1e13
            })
            .set('season', season)
            .set('system:time_start', image.date().millis())
          return ee.Feature(null, properties)
        })
      )
    }
  )).flatten()

var ts = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: features,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  yProperty: 'LST_Day_1km',
  seriesProperty: 'season'
}).setOptions({
  title: '2001-2022 LST Time Series',
  vAxis: {
    title: 'LST (°C)'
  }
})
print(ts)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cb914853dd8e3510b1da9b23b6da2ae2